# Liner gradient on left, center and right

Tags: css

I am trying to learn how to use linear gradient but am still not getting the syntax 100% as you can see in my code:

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 55px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, #ed1c24); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000, #ed1c24); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #00, #ed1c24); /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ed1c24); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1" style="text-align:center;margin:auto;color:#888888;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
Gradient Background
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.</p>
```

How can I use the gradient so that I have the black on the left fading to red in the center and then fading again to red on the right?

For now I could do on the left and the center but am struggling to put on the right as well.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 4):

Just add black color again to make fade to black again.

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 55px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ed1c24, #000);
}
```

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 55px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ed1c24, #000);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1" style="text-align:center;margin:auto;color:#888888;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
  Gradient Background
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #dd2323 50%, #dd2323 52%, #000000 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%,#dd2323 50%,#dd2323 52%,#000000 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%,#dd2323 50%,#dd2323 52%,#000000 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 55px;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
   background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* Safari */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Opera  */
     background: -moz-radial-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Firefox */
   background: radial-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1" style="text-align:center;margin:auto;color:#888888;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
Gradient Background
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.</p>
```